# Finding historical reputation requirements

Tags: discussion, tags, reputation, data-explorer, data-dump

Stack Exchange sites have different reputation thresholds that allow users to do various things. For example, on Stack Overflow, creating tags requires 1,500 reputation, while on Database Administrators, the requirement is only 300. Moreover, reputation requirements also change within sites over time. I know for instance that in August 2011, Database Administrators only required 150 reputation to add tags.

What would be the easiest way of determining the reputation threshold to add tags (or other privileges) on a given Stack Exchange site at a given (historical) point in time?

I've considered a few possibilities, but I wonder if there is something easier:

- According to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58587/reputation-requirements-compared) question and answer, reputation thresholds change for most sites depending on their status (e.g., whether they are a launched SE 2.0 site, in beta, so on). Assuming that's true, if I could determine the dates each site made the relevant transitions (and the thresholds associated with each status/stage), I would then be able to determine the reputation thresholds. Does anyone know how to determine the transition dates?
- Is there an easy way to compute historical reputation? If so, then I could use the correspondence of who is adding tags and their historical reputation level to infer the thresholds.
- Some other source of data? I've scoured the CC dump and the [data explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/), but I can't seem to find something that will give me the information I need. Perhaps I'm missing something obvious though?